lottie-react-native skewed in react native expo app
for some reason lottie-react-native is always displaying a skewed version and not the original in my app. I have tried every trick I know and still same issue. currently using the following dependencies
 "expo": "~51.0.8",
 "lottie-react-native": "6.7.0",
here's my component.
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import { ICON, NumFormat, ThemedStatusBar } from '../../../components/global'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native'

const PaymentSuccess = (props) => {
    const data = props.route.params.payLoad
    const {navigate} = useNavigation()
    const makeReceipt =()=>{
   // data comes here
    }
    return (
        <SafeAreaView  className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 flex-1">
            <ThemedStatusBar />
            <View className="px-10 py-10 flex-row justify-between">
                <TouchableOpacity className="" onPress={()=>navigate("btTab")}>
                    <ICON type="Entypo" name="home" size={28} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <View className="flex justify-center gap-y-8 px-8">

                <View className=" items-center justify-center pt-28 space-y-10">
                    <View className="h-32 w-32 rounded-full"> 
                        <LottieView autoPlay loop={false} source={require('../../../assets/lottie/transaction-completed.json')} style={{ height:"100%", width:"100%"}} />
                    </View>
          
                    <Text className="text-center font-InterBold text-2xl text-black dark:text-white">Transaction Successful</Text>
                </View>

                <View className="space-y-2 px-2">
                    <Text className="text-center font-InterSemibold text-sm text-black dark:text-white">Your Transfer of ₦{<NumFormat num={data.amount} />} is on its way to {data.res_name}</Text>
                    <Text className="text-center font-Inter text-xs  text-black dark:text-white">You will recieve confirmation shortly</Text>
                </View>


                <View className="py-16 mt-10 px-6">

                    <TouchableOpacity className="flex-row justify-center items-center rounded-2xl bg-brand1  dark:bg-brand3  px-12 py-3" onPress={() => makeReceipt()}>
                        <ICON type="MaterialIcons" name="receipt-long" size={24} color="white" />
                        <Text className='text-sm font-InterSemiBold text-white ml-2'>Share Reciept</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>

    )
}

export default PaymentSuccess




I have the same problem. The strange thing is, files I downloaded last week work perfectly. But files downloaded this week are all broken or skewed. I have no solution at the moment, except for contacting support.

Yes i noticed that too. some files work very well while for some it's just hell to work with no solution or fix for this issue so far.

I just created a new account on LottieFiles and downloaded the same animation and it WORKS. I downloaded the same exact file with my old standard account, and it does not work... Either they want us to pay up or subscribe, or this is a very weird bug.
